# Requiring ui router stateparams and/or redirecting

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to know if anyone has come up with a way to require state params when using ui router with angular.js and/or how to redirect if param is not specified. I would prefer not to have to put controller code in the stateProvider config, but am open to any suggestions.

I've come close with some things like:

```
if (typeof $stateParams.myId == 'undefined') {
 ...
}
```

But I cannot put that in a resolve, so I am not sure where or how to check that. I have an abstract state with children and the abstract state have the stateparam....

```
.state('mystate', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/state/:permalink',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
})

.state('mystate.config', {
    url: '/config',
    templateUrl: 'partials/conf/config.html'
})
```

TIA

Comment: Could we see your route/state definitions? Basically if you are specifying the stateParam as part of the url pattern - then it is impossible to my knowledge for you to actually enter that state without the stateParam being defined.

Comment: I answered a similar question days ago, check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100634/conditionally-navigate-to-state-with-angular-ui-router/28101050#28101050

Comment: The applicable stateParam is in the question... and you are correct you cannot "enter" the state. However the state has children and if the param is missing, you will get a blank page (expected), which is why I want to send them elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

OK...

Thanks to  levi... I have this partially working:

```
  .state('conference', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/conference/:permalink',
    data: {hasPerma: true},
    module: 'conf',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>',
  })

  .state('conference.config', {
    url: '/config',
    templateUrl: 'partials/conf/config.html'
  })
```

... this is allowing me to check to toState data, but the fromState module (or data) do not show up for some reason:

```
  .run(['$state', '$stateParams', '$rootScope', function($state, $stateParams, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
      console.log(toState.data.hasPerma); //working
      console.log('from: ' + fromState.module); //not showing up
    })
}])
```

So if I got to the base url and /conference/hello/config I can see the to info, but not the from ;-(